# (How) Does TPL use (CLR) Thread Pool?

Tags: .net, threadpool, task-parallel-library

I am currently researching Task Parallel Library and I read somewhere that TPL actually uses thread pool mechanism from CLR-Level. I couldn't find any article confirming this information. I know, TPL has task queues for each thread and uses some special work-stealing algorithm for balancing. As far as I know, it creates one thread for each processor. Thread pools started to use task objects of TPL since .NET 4.

I can not understand how TPL uses the thread pool. Thread-Pool pattern states, the work items are queued and the free threads in thread pool takes one from this queue. TPL however store the items (tasks) to queues of threads and work-stealing works if needed... Thus, quite differently. Where is my mistake?

extra question: As this was my first Stack Overflow question, I am not sure if it was suitable. Is it?

Comment: (It's absolutely fine as an SO question, by the way.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In TPL, a [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321418.aspx) is responsible for actually queuing the tasks up for execution. The [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default.aspx) scheduler will use the thread-pool - but I believe it's the new thread pool implementation which actually does the work-stealing cleverness.

Daniel Moth has a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20221205203227/http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx) with some more details which you may find useful.

Comment: The article is very useful, thanks. I understand the reason for my confusion: Task logic and work-stealing were actually designed as a part of TPL. But the implementation is in thread-pool. This evolved thread-pool to a "pool with work-stealing". Thanks again.

Comment: @jonSkeet that link is no longer available

Comment: @PreetSangha: There are three links... it would have been helpful if you'd said which was broken, and whether you'd tried to find an equivalent. I've replaced the blog post link with a Wayback Machine version, but in future please try to improve things yourself rather than *just* reporting the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Apologies - you are right I should have said which one.