# Task Parallel Library : How many thread does the application spawn?

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

We are now using Task Parallel Library by implementing Task.Factory.StartNew(). Is there any way to check how many threads does the application spawn when executing the task ?

Currently we are running the application in dual core processor in the development environment.

Answer (score 3):

TPL doesn't spawn any threads when executing a task unless you use a custom scheduler or you pass the  TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning option. Even then, it is up to the TaskScheduler used to decide how to treat long-running tasks.

TPL schedules individual tasks to a threadpool for execution by the pool's threads. Each Thread has its own queue to reduce conflicts in multi-core machines. If a thread is too busy, the Framework uses some work-stealing magic to assign the task to an idle thread in the same thread pool.

Check [How does the tpl use the CLR thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534839/how-does-tpl-use-clr-thread-pool) for a bit more info, and this post by [Daniel Moth](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx) for details on work stealing.