# Should I not use TPL when I need scalability?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Threadpool threads are important reuseable threads  which (in asp.net for example ) - helps serving requests.

As opposed to the primitive `new Thread().start(....)` which is NOT using threadpool thread  , and does not support cancellation tokens  , continuity , result value - there is no doubt that TPL is the preferred strategy.

But the problem is that `Task` **also** [uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4534902/859154) threadpool threads.

> In TPL, a TaskScheduler is responsible for actually queuing the tasks
>   up for execution. The Default scheduler will use the thread-pool .

And this makes me wonder :

Say I have a site with many concurrent users , and I need to do 3 *compute bound* tasks ( non-IO)  for each user.

I'm afraid that the threadpool will have no threads left ( because I  will do the 3  compute operation (for each user) via TASK which uses Threadpool Thread. - which will cause creating NEW threadpool threads.

Which leads me to the conclusion that when I need scalability - it's better to use the old fashion `new Thread().start(...)` ?

What am I missing? Are we back to square one ?

Comment: I would be considering putting these tasks into another *process* so that you're not starving asp.net. New process = new set of threadpool threads, and in that process, they'd be dedicated to these tasks. So, for example, a windows service and some form of inter-process communication from the website to the service.

Comment: But it's much easier control thread pool than control number of thread you have created. In case you create huge number of thread you can get worse performance.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what ipc communication ? Socket ? Mmf ? I dont want to use wcf for that . What is the fastest way ? Can u pls provide link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rarely need to use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` in ASP.NET. These APIs are for CPU-bound work, and it usually doesn't make sense to offload CPU-bound work to another thread while processing an HTTP request (unlike with a client-side UI app). That would only hurt scalability. Just do the work on the current thread.

If you need to spawn a long-running task with life-time across multiple HTTP requests, use a separate process a suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever in the comments, e.g., a WCF service on the same or a separate host.

That said, you still can have a non-pool thread wrapped as `Task` with all goodies, at least with the current TPL implementation. It's created when you use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Inside such thread, `Thread.IsThreadPoolThread` will be `false`. This may prevent `ThreadPool` starvation, but certainly will increase the working set of the process. Moreover, such threads are not reused by TPL like `ThreadPool` threads, so it may be quite costly to create non-pool threads repetitively.

As an alternative to `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, it's easy to wrap `new Thread().Start()` as a `Task` using `TaskCompletionSource`, with the same cancellation, exception and result propagation logic.

Yet another idea is to **use a custom task scheduler** which always queues the task on a new thread:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new { Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId });

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => Console.WriteLine(new { 
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}),
            CancellationToken.None,
            // hide the scheduler from inner tasks
            TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler,
            NewThreadTaskScheduler.Scheduler);

        task.Wait();
    }
}

class NewThreadTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    public static readonly NewThreadTaskScheduler Scheduler = 
        new NewThreadTaskScheduler();

    NewThreadTaskScheduler()
    {
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            base.TryExecuteTask(task);
        });
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(
        Task task, 
        bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel { 
        get { return Int32.MaxValue; } }
}
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir, another idea is to use a simple custom task scheduler, check the update I posted.

Comment: What do you mean by saying not to use thread but do on the same thread? I want to use all my cors ....again each user runs 3 cpu task , 5 sec each ( for example) , so i want to use allcors , which is why i dot understand your sentence :" just do it on the current thread" .... Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, usually, in ASP.NET you want to serve as many concurrent HTTP requests as possible, that's what you need your CPU cores for. So you want to use `async` controller methods as much as possible and you do *not* want to use `Task.Run`. Unless you want to give any particular request a priority over others, so they will be put on hold while you do the parallel work for this one (to deliver the response to the client ASAP).