# TPL with LongRunning state and thread synchronization and performance

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have one doubt regarding the usage of TPL with the LongRunning state.

From MSDN 
The purpose of the TPL is to make developers more productive by simplifying the process of adding parallelism and concurrency to applications. The TPL **scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processor cores that are available.** Another benefit of the TPL is, that **you don't have to deal with thread creation and synchronization.**

But if I set the LongRunning option, TPL assigns a dedicated thread from outside of thread pool. So in that case it will work some what similar to the traditional threading (What I believe, please correct if I am wrong). So in such a scenario, will TPL itself deal with thread creation and synchronization as mentioned above? Also will it automatically/internally scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processor cores or developer need to write code to handle all those?

Comment: The statement in bold applies to `Parallel.For` family of TPL APIs. It doesn't apply to `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`, where you have explicit control over the degree of parallelism.

Comment: @Noseratio: isn't default Run(f)/StartNew(f) executing the tasks on threadpool? I mean, without manual control options. If so, it's already scaled up to the available number of procs I presume?

Answer (score 1):

> The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most
>   efficiently use all the processor cores that are available. Another
>   benefit of the TPL is, that you don't have to deal with thread
>   creation and synchronization.

This statement applies to `Parallel.For` family of TPL APIs. It doesn't apply to `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`, where you have explicit control over the degree of parallelism.

For `Task.Run` (and `Task.Factory.StartNew` with default options, for that matter), there's no intelligent "scaling". It's just plain round-robin execution of work items, much like with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. This may actually engage all available pool threads (up to `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads`), and then queue new tasks for deferred execution as busy pool thread becomes available. It also may be a subject to [the thread pool stuttering issue](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/07/08/clr-thread-pool-injection-stuttering-problems/).

Using `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `LongRunning` is only different in that you may escape the thread pool stuttering issue, but in the end you may simply exhaust the OS memory and other resources, as an OS thread is a very expensive resource.

In case with with `Parallel.For` etc., the TPL scheduler is much more intelligent. It doesn't waste threads on one-thread-per-work-item basis. Rather, it has a quite complicated imperative logic, taking into account the number of CPUs/cores and possibly some other runtime metrics.

**Updated** to address the comment, here's a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int max = 50;
            int delay = 30; // ~30s per work item

            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(max, max);

            Console.WriteLine("starting, threads: {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);

            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, max).Select(n => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("task: {0}, threads: {1}, pool thread: {2}", 
                    n, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count, Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);

                for (int i = 0; i < delay * 1000; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            })).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine("waiting, threads: {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("done, threads: {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output (Release build, no debugger attached, .NET 4.5, 4 core CPU):

```
starting, threads: 3
task: 0, threads: 11, pool thread: True
task: 2, threads: 11, pool thread: True
waiting, threads: 11
task: 1, threads: 11, pool thread: True
task: 3, threads: 11, pool thread: True
...
task: 48, threads: 56, pool thread: True
task: 49, threads: 57, pool thread: True
done, threads: 47
```

It confirms both the growing and the stuttering behavior of the `ThreadPool`, up to the `max` number of threads. New threads are created with ~500ms delays.

Now, if we add `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to `Task.Factory.StartNew`, we eliminated the stuttering, and we're no longer limited by the `ThreadPool` size, but we'll still end up engaging up to the `max` number of new threads, one per task (depending on how much each work item takes to execute).

> Also will it automatically/internally scales the degree of concurrency
>   dynamically to most efficiently use all the processor cores or
>   developer need to write code to handle all those?

Thus, if the developer wants to use TPL's `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` APIs, he or she does need to handle the level of parallelism manually. That's not to difficult though, e.g., with `SemaphoreSlim`.

Comment: That blog post is from 2006, please review http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx from 2008 about .Net4. Just FYI, I don't claim you're wrong here. Threadpool still can be starved.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, my explanation appears to be correct, check the update.

Comment: All I wanted to say is that if TPL is configured correctly (LongRunning, etc), there's no point in manually managing pool size. It's designed to handle many small jobs, but still adapts in critical cases if you have bugs in the code that start starving it. Many long jobs should not be queued onto the default threadpool. They should have their own threads, or, if you need to limit that, then you should create your own additional threadpool and shedule that long tasks to it. That's why a LongRunning option exists, and why TPL accepts different schedulers. It does not make Run/StartNew any worse.

Answer (score 0):

There's always "traditional threading" somewhere down below.

Native threads are "heavy". If you'd execute one thread per task and then create really many tasks (thus threads), then you could starve/stall the process (or even whole machine or some systems). This makes it impossible/unfeasible to register many tiny operations and handle in that way and that obstacle impacts your code architecture.

This is where thread pool comes in. Changing the idea to not run one thread per job, but to have some threads pooled and let them work on a shared task queue, limits the amount of threads to exactly N of the pool, and you get the benefit of background message processing.

Sketching that idea, it's important to notice that the thread pool is (usually) limited to some N threads. This means that if you register many long running tasks to the thread pool, you may starve it. Threadpool works the best if it processes tiny quick jobs.

This is why TPL allow you to specify which jobs are "long". They want to give you ability to relieve stress from threadpool. With Task-based ops, it's very important for the threadpool to keep running. Allow it to be starved, and all tasks will have to wait for some long op to complete. That's totally not what it was all about!

I'm sure that TPL handles the creation and management of that separate thread, dedicated to LongRunning jobs.

As for the second question - actually I don't know. "Choosing the most efficient" is a hard task in general, so I'm pretty safe to say that "no, it does not do that in all cases" :))) I think the scaling of the DoP/DoC in TPL is as simple as adjusting the threadpool size to the number of logical processors on the machine. Separate threads for LongRunning jobs will still be created over the limit, so the ThreadPool is safe. Including them in DoP/DoC limit would starve the pool in just the same way, as it would decrease the number of available threads. I don't think TPL does much more in terms of scaling. Maaybe it schedules child tasks that operate on the same data on the same threads to get some caching or NUMA boost.. but I don't know, that's quite a far guess anyways.

I've just found an article you may find interesting: 
[New and Improved CLR 4 Thread Pool Engine](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx) - I'm pretty sure that default TaskScheduler uses that pool. (from JohnSkeet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4534902/717732)

And another example, someone performed a few tests regarding threadpool sizes and LongRunning flag: [Threadpool thread starvation - a practical example](http://cjbhaines.co.uk/238/threadpool-thread-starvation-a-practical-example/)

Answer (score 0):

> So in such a scenario, will TPL itself deal with thread creation and synchronization as mentioned above?

A `LongRunning` `Task` is nothing more that a Thread wrapped in a Task. This has the benefit that you can query its status, set continuations, wait for it and have errors propagated. You can also use combinators such as `WaitAll`.

That's all there is to the `LongRunning` option.

> Also will it automatically/internally scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processor cores or developer need to write code to handle all those?

How would you "scale" a single thread/task? It is inherently unscalable. You need multiple independent units of work (such as tasks or data items) to use multiple processors.